# Check if the data is duplicated for each group

Tags: r

I would like to check my data and assign value for duplicated value for a group of data in R. In this case, the group is ID.

This is how the data looks like.

```
ID, SET
1,1 
1,1
1,3
1,2
2,1
2,1
2,1
2,1
3,2
3,2
3,2
3,2
```

I would like to get this result.

```
ID, SET, Index
1,1,0
1,1,0
1,3,0
1,2,0
2,1,1
2,1,1
2,1,1
2,1,1
3,2,1
3,2,1
3,2,1
3,2,1
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: I don't follow the logic here - what is the `Index` column supposed to indicate - the number of unique values? Can you show which rows evaluate to 1 in the `Index` column?

Comment: What is the logic here? You have `1,1` duplicated and yet you want `0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After grouping by 'ID', create the 'index' column by checking the number of distinct elements in 'SET'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(ID) %>%
     mutate(index = as.integer(n_distinct(SET) ==1))
# A tibble: 12 x 3
# Groups:   ID [3]
#      ID   SET index
#   <int> <dbl> <int>
# 1     1     1     0
# 2     1     1     0
# 3     1     3     0
# 4     1     2     0
# 5     2     1     1
# 6     2     1     1
# 7     2     1     1
# 8     2     1     1
# 9     3     2     1
#10     3     2     1
#11     3     2     1
#12     3     2     1
```

---

Or another option is `base R`

```
df1$index <- +(with(df1, ave(SET, ID, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))) == 1))
```

Or an option with `table`

```
transform(df1, index = ID %in% names(which(table(unique(df1)$ID) == 1)))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L), SET = c(1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that. Thanks for your help @akrun.